# How to rename iterably object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object

Every Object properties have underscored the first letter;
I wanna delete this first substring, and try the string method "replace" to all object properties, but it's not working in this case.

```
// nested object
const posts = {
  // ...
  'post-meta-fields': {
    _bg_advantages_home: [''],
    _bg_banner_home: ['35'],
    _bg_info_1_home: ['41'],
    _bg_info_2_home: [''],
    _bg_offers_home: ['38'],
    _bg_sales_home: ['36'],
    _bg_video_home: ['']
  }
  // ...
};
// I tried this, but its not working
for (const key in posts['post-meta-fields']) {
  for (let key_2 in key) {
    key_2 = key_2.replace('_', '');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this,

```
const tempObj = {};
for(let key in posts["post-meta-fields"]) {
     const modifiedKey = key.replace('_','');
     tempObj[modifiedKey] = posts["post-meta-fields"][key]
}
posts["post-meta-fields"] = tempObj;
```

Hope you got some idea!

Answer (score 0):

Now you just need to delete the old key and add the new key:

```
let newKey = key_2.replace('_','');
key.newKey = key[key_2];
delete key[key_2];
```

Comment: Should be `posts['post-meta-fields'][newKey]`, instead of `key.newKey`...dot operator won't work there, and base object shouldn't be `key`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new key with the modified name and add the appropriate values to it and then delete the old key with the underscore .
**Without** using any extra **space**
Time complexity : O(n)
Space complexity : O(1)

```
// nested object
const posts = {
  // ...
  'post-meta-fields': {
    _bg_advantages_home: [''],
    _bg_banner_home: ['35'],
    _bg_info_1_home: ['41'],
    _bg_info_2_home: [''],
    _bg_offers_home: ['38'],
    _bg_sales_home: ['36'],
    _bg_video_home: ['']
  }
  // ...
};
// I tried this, and it is working
for (const key in posts['post-meta-fields']) {
  let newKey = key.replace("_","");
  posts['post-meta-fields'][newKey] = posts['post-meta-fields'][key];
  delete posts['post-meta-fields'][key];
}
console.log(posts);
```

```js
// nested object
const posts = {
  // ...
  'post-meta-fields': {
    _bg_advantages_home: [''],
    _bg_banner_home: ['35'],
    _bg_info_1_home: ['41'],
    _bg_info_2_home: [''],
    _bg_offers_home: ['38'],
    _bg_sales_home: ['36'],
    _bg_video_home: ['']
  }
  // ...
};
// I tried this, and it is working
for (const key in posts['post-meta-fields']) {
  let newKey = key.replace("_","");
  posts['post-meta-fields'][newKey] = posts['post-meta-fields'][key];
  delete posts['post-meta-fields'][key];
}
console.log(posts);
```